# printing messages to the screen and a file

Tags: perl

I have perl script that I am running in Windows. In the script I call another perl scrip.  I am trying get both of those scripts to print to the cmd window and a file. This basically how I am doing the call

```
    using IO::Tee
    open (my $file, '>>', "C:\\Logs\\logfile.txt") or die "couldn't open log file:  $!";
    me $tee = IO::Tee->new(\*STDOUT, $file);
    # doing some stuff 
    print $tee "log about what i just did";
    # do more stuff 
    print $tee "more logs";
    print $tee `c:\\secondScript.pl arg1`;
    print $tee "done with script";
```

The second script is basically

```
    # do stuff
    print "script 2 log about stuff";
    # do more stuff
    print "script 2 log about more stuff";
    print "script 2 done";
```

This does get everything to the screen and a file.  However, I don't see the "script 2 log about stuff", "script 2 log about more stuff", and "script 2 done" until after script 2 has finished.  I would like to see all of that stream to the screen and the file as soon as the print is reached.

Comment: Try turning off output buffering in the second script.  `$| = 1`;

Answer (score 3):

Printing to STDOUT is usually *line buffered* (to speed things up) when output goes to a terminal and *block buffered* otherwise (e.g. when redirecting output to a file).
You can think of it as if anything printed is first placed into a buffer (typically 4096 bytes large) and only when the buffer is full (i.e. 4096 characters were printed), it gets output to the screen.

**line buffered** means the output is only shown on screen after a `\n` is found (or the buffer is exhausted). You don't have `\n`s in your 2nd script, so no output is shown until either a) `\n` comes, b) buffer is full, or c) the script ends.

**block buffered** means the output is shown only when the buffer is full. `\n`s don't influence this here (except for counting as one character).

To avoid buffering there's a *magic variable* called `$|`. From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (scroll down to the `$|` section):

> If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or
>   print on the currently selected output channel.

So you could append `"\n"` to your print statements or – better – set `$| = 1;` on top of your 2nd script (only once, not for each `print`). This will slow down the output of the 2nd script (in theory) but for a few lines it will make no difference.